# Python - Optimizing combination of 2 among N with N very large

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, combinations, large-data

I am trying to find pairs of elements that satisfy a certain condition. More precisely, I want to form combination of 2 (unordered) elements among 50,000 elements such that a certain condition is respected.

My dataset contains 50,000 elements with unique identifiers and a few observables (location and cutoff). I want to form unordered pairs of 2 elements such that the distance between the two paired-elements is below a given cutoff.

My script so far is the following.

```
# Load the dataset (I have a custom function for it called loadFile)
df = loadFile(path_input,filename_input)

# Reset the index because I want to use the column "index" from 0 to 49,999
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)

# Initiate the list of pairs & get the number of elements
pairs = list()
nb_rows = df.shape[0]

# Loop over all the rows of my dataframe
for ind_x, x in df.iterrows():
    # Just print to know where we stand from 1 to 50,000
    print("{} out of {}".format(ind_x+1,nb_rows))
    # Loop over all the rows of my dataframe
    for ind_y, y in df.iterrows():
        # We only consider the y-row if it was not covered yet by the previous pairs
        # I also don't want to cover the case where both elements are equal
        if ind_x<ind_y:
            # Here is a custom condition (a simple function) returning a boolean
            if distance(x["location"],y["location"])<x["cutoff"]:
                pairs.append((x["id"],y["id"]))
```

Virtually, if my custom condition is always respected, my script could go over all the 50,000 * 49,999 / 2 ~ **1 250 millions** possible pairs..

For one "ind_x" element, the current loop takes approximately 5 seconds to run, which makes 50,000 * 5 / (60²) = 69 hours to run the script (a lot).

Is there any way to speed up my script, either the loop itself or to modify my approach to save time ?

Thank you in advance,

M

Comment: iterrows() is generally not recommended.

Comment: Hi Joseph,
Thanks for your answer. Do you advice me to use .itertuples instead?

Comment: https://medium.com/@rtjeannier/pandas-101-cont-9d061cb73bfc 
Take a look at this article.

Comment: If you are able to fully merge the two frames, then checking whether the condition is met would be very simple, and much faster. But the logic to then only include the row that would have matched with your loop (with the exclusion of previous matches that had matched) might be complicated to implement. At the very least, this simplifies it to a single loop over the at most 50,000 groups, and I'm guessing it can be done without it.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the classic problem of finding neighborhood sets.  As long as your distance is Euclidean, there are lots of specialized packages with fast methods to solve it, but a good option is to leverage scipy's [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

def close_point_pairs(X, max_d):
    # create the tree from the data points
    tree = cKDTree(X)

    # find all pairs of points 
    pairs = tree.query_ball_tree(tree,max_d)

    # pair indices
    return np.array([(x, pt) for x, ptlist in enumerate(pairs) for pt in ptlist if pt>x])
```

This will create a numpy array with all of the index pairs.  Its pretty fast, with most of the runtime consumed by the last pair expansion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(500*np.random.random(size=10**4), columns=['location'])
%timeit close_point_pairs(df['location'].values[:,np.newaxis], max_d=1.0)
530 ms ± 123 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Note I had to add np.newaxis because the points were only 1D, its not clear what your location points are, but if they are of higher dimension, you should remove that.

If you need the unique ids from the original DataFrame, you can just index back into it or create a translation dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a close look to that!